# Accessing Session Message across two seperate pages

Tags: php, session, echo

I currently have two pages. The first processes some data, and then redirects to the second page. In the first page, I have specified a Session message, however, when I try to access the session message on the new page, it says that the index is unidentified?

PAGE ONE:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['customer'] = 'hello';
header('Location: ordersuccess.php?success');
?>
```

PAGE TWO:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 include 'Includes/connection.php';
echo $_SESSION['customer'];
?>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: PHP sessions store a PHPSESSID Cookie in the user's browser. If the user's browser is configured to ignore cookies then your session state doesn't get transferred between request pages. You could try putting a `print_r($_SESSION);` in your second page to verify that there's nothing in session storage.